# Using boost::chrono without linking to it

Tags: boost, c++-chrono

The [boost::chrono documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.chrono_hpp.conf.header_only) says

> When BOOST_CHRONO_HEADER_ONLY is defined the lib is header-only.

Even with this defined, I'm getting linker error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib'
```

Is this a documentation bug? Or does `chrono` really support header only usage?

Comment: How about a self-contained sample?  Make sure that `BOOST_CHRONO_HEADER_ONLY` is defined before you include any boost files

Comment: The question was posted after trying what the documentation says. The question is does `chrono` really support header only usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last version of Boost says 
"
 Boost.Chrono can be configured as a header-only library defining BOOST_CHRONO_HEADER_ONLY. However Boost.Chrono depends on the non header-only library Boost.System, so that you will need to link with boost_system.

Boost.System has un undocumented feature (use of macro BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY) to make it header only, but it is buggy (see #7347 duplicate symbol while BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY is defined) 
"

I think the bug has been fixed at least in trunk.

Comment: Apparently that bug is _not_ fixed (well) in 1_55: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d4fbf815e4373f1 (however, if you have the full source tree, it does appear to work). YMMV